# How to set missing value in dataframe.csv(sys.stdout, na_rep='NULL') for the first row of dataframe containing column headers(the highlighted portion)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, na, sys

[Set missing value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7Ygk.png)

Tried data.to_csv(sys.stdout,na_rep='NULL') but it doesnt apply to first row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's your `index`'s name - it cannot be ignored.

Set index name instead using `df.index.name = 'yourname'` or remove the index from the `to_csv` using `df.to_csv(index=False)`